# Unable to load image logo + SINTIA wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I am using SINTIA theme on wordpress 3.8.

I am having a trouble in loading image logo at the heading, once i click insert nothing happens.

after searching the internet i found out that i need to downgrade my wordpress version but i am asking if there is another solution maybe based on CSS or PHP to solve this issue.

Here is the page
    [http://69.89.31.99/~svelteli/]

Thank you for your support

Comment: Can you show the code for how you are currently trying to do it?

Comment: Hello @Amber, Sorry for my late reply, i am using the Theme settings after installing it on wordpress, am not a developper i am just a graphic designer but can apply Css codes if advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the theme. The issue is you need to update your theme to the newest version (Sintia 6). The older version of the themes are not compatible with the new versions of WordPress.

Once I updated the theme it resolved my issue.

Comment: THANK YOU A LOT:) I HAVE CONTACTED VAMTAM FOR THIS ISSUE AND YES YOU ARE RIGHT:)

Comment: You're welcome! Could you mark this as the correct answer? This will help others know there is a solution to this issue

Answer (score 0):

The solution was by contacting vamtam and getting information to update the SINTIA Theme to the newest version, of course some credentials are required so they be sure that the them was purchased from their site.